# How to solve $y''(x) + \alpha = 0$ using the Finite volume method for one-dimensional steady state diffusion?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am sharing something that I am seeing for the first time.

I must solve the following boundary value problem
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
&y''(x)+ \alpha = 0, \ x \in I = [0,1], \ \alpha:= \text{constant}\\
&y(0)=1, \ y(1)=0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
using the finite volume method. In particular, I am asked to:

1. Take a uniform partition of $I$ and use it to model the DE above using the finite volume method.
2. Explain the linear-algebraic system that arises from said modeling.
3. Under what conditions has the algebraic system only one solution?

Generally I know how to approach this. However I must use the $1$D finite volume method.

## OVERVIEW OF FINITE VOLUME METHOD

What I know is that we must bring the system to the form
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
&\dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \Gamma \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right) + S_y = 0, \ x \in [0,1]\\
&y(0) = y(L) = c
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and we must split the section $[0,1]$ into uniform intervals like so:
\begin{align}
&\int_{CV}\dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \Gamma \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right)dx + \int_{CV}S dx=0\\
\implies &\Gamma \dfrac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{\rho} - \Gamma \dfrac{dy}{dx} \bigg|_{\omega} + S \Delta x = 0\\
\implies &\Gamma_{\rho} \dfrac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{\rho} - \Gamma_{\omega} \dfrac{dy}{dx} \bigg|_{\omega} + S \Delta x = 0\\
\implies &\Gamma_{\rho} \left(\dfrac{\Phi_{\epsilon} - \Phi_{\rho}}{\Delta x} \right) - \Gamma_{\omega} \left( \dfrac{\Phi_{\rho} - \Phi_{\omega}}{\Delta x} \right) + S \Delta x = 0.
\end{align}

At this point we take $\Gamma_{\rho} = \Gamma_{\omega} = \Gamma$ and
\begin{align}
&\dfrac{\Gamma}{\Delta x} \left( \Phi_{\epsilon} -\Phi_{\rho} - \Phi_{\rho} + \Phi_{\omega} \right) + S \Delta x = 0\\
\implies &\dfrac{\Gamma}{\Delta x} \left( \Phi_{\epsilon} -2\Phi_{\rho} + \Phi_{\omega} \right) + S \Delta x = 0
\end{align}
which creates a differential equation of differences as so:
\begin{align}
\alpha_{\rho}\Phi_{\rho} = \alpha_{\omega}\phi_{\omega}+ \alpha_{\epsilon} \phi_{\epsilon} + S_{u}.
\end{align}

Now generally this **should** give us a linear system like so:
\begin{align}
&\alpha_1 \phi_1 - \alpha_2 \phi_2 - \alpha_0 \phi_0 = S_{\phi_1}\Delta x\\
&\alpha_2 \phi_2 - \alpha_3 \phi_3 - \alpha_1 \phi_1 = S_{\phi_2}\Delta x\\
&\alpha_3 \phi_3 - \alpha_4 \phi_4 - \alpha_2 \phi_2 = S_{\phi_3}\Delta x\\
&\alpha_4 \phi_4 - \alpha_1 \phi_1 - \alpha_3 \phi_3 = S_{\phi_4}\Delta x 
\end{align}
where $\alpha_0 \phi_0, \ \alpha_1 \phi_1$ are known.

In linear equation form, we have
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & -\alpha_2 & 0 & 0\\
-\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_3 & 0\\
0 & -\alpha_2 & \alpha_3 & \alpha_4\\
0 & 0 & -\alpha_3 & \alpha_4\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \\ \phi_3 \\ \phi_4\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
S_{\phi_1}\Delta x + \alpha_0 \phi_0\\
S_{\phi_2}\Delta x\\
S_{\phi_3}\Delta x\\
S_{\phi_4}\Delta x + \alpha_1 \phi_1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where I can use already known linear algebra tools.

However what I outlined above is general and I need some help in applying it to the particular problem. I guess what I ask is for an example of finite volume method for 1D.

**EDIT 1:** I found that this method is called the Crank-Nicolson method, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method). However I still have no idea how to approach this.

**EDIT 2:** I found that this method has been somewhat documented here [in the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method_for_one-dimensional_steady_state_diffusion). However I still struggle in applying it to my problem.

Comment: This seems like a really terrible way to solve $y''+\alpha=0$ ;)

Comment: @FShrike maybe so, but that's what I am tasked to do.

Comment: I know. I have +1 and I hope someone can help

Comment: @FShrike thank you. Do you know of any way to find a simple 1D finite volume method example or something similar? Maybe a solved problem or something.

Comment: I have never heard of the finite volume method, sorry.

Comment: @FShrike it's really popular in partial differential equations (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method), however it's the first time I see it on 1D.

Comment: Is the idea to get the solution as limit of a PDE solution like $y_t=y_{xx}+\alpha$? Then the application of PDE specific methods would make sense.

Comment: The Crank-Nicholson method applied to ODEs can be resumed by the formula: given $y(x_0)$

$$
y'(x) = f(x,y(x))\Rightarrow y_n = y_{n-1}+\frac{\Delta x}{2}(f(x_n,y_n)+f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1}))
$$

Comment: @Cesareo fair point, how can that be applied to my problem?

Comment: Well, I outlined my ideas on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Crank-Nicholson method applied to ODEs can be resumed by the formula: given $y(x_0)$

$$
y'(x) = f(x,y(x))\Rightarrow y_n = y_{n-1}+\frac{\Delta x}{2}(f(x_n,y_n)+f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1}))
$$

now $y''(x)+\alpha = 0$ can be handled as

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
y'_1(x) &=& y_2(x)\\
y'_2(x) &=& -\alpha
\end{array}
\right.
$$

so the discretization method furnishes

$$
\cases{y_1(n) = y_1(n-1)+\frac{\Delta}{2}(y_2(n)+y_2(n-1))\\ y_2(n) = y_2(n-1) - \alpha\Delta 
}
$$

and solving this recurrence we get

$$
\cases{
y_1(n) = -\frac{1}{2} \alpha  \Delta^2 n^2+c_2 \Delta n+c_1\\  y_2(n) = c_2-\alpha  \Delta n
}
$$

Here $\Delta = \frac 1N$ and the boundary conditions are $y_1(0) = y_1(N) = 0$

etc.

Comment: Good points, but how can we end up with a linear-algebraic system as outlined above?

Comment: Considering variable $\Delta$'s with three or four internal points....

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I do not understand what you say :(

Comment: I applied the method for a fixed step width $\Delta$ but the method can be applied as well for variable steps like in finite element methods...

Comment: Hmm I was hoping something like my linear system above could come out of it? Maybe setting step number to $4$ or something?